# Date Picker is not working in AVD Android 2.2 API 8

Tags: android, datetime, datetimepicker

I have taken the example `Date Picker` from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html and it is running fine when `AVD` setting are as follows

Target platform 4.22 and `API Level 17`. But when I am testing the same code with `AVD` setting as follows it is crashing

Target platform 2.2 and `API Level 8`

My code looks like this

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.datepicker;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
                
    }
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new ShowCalendar();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### ShowCalendar.java

```
package com.example.datepicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ShowCalendar extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
    
}
```

Please note that I have treid to replace the Activity class with FragmentActivity class in MainActivity.java as it is hinted in the example. But the still the same issue. Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Import

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

If you want to use `Fragment` below API 11 you need to import `android.support.v4.app` which provides backward compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Use following steps-

1.Change the Activity to extend the FragmentActivity class

2.Change the call to the getFragmentManager() method to the getSupportFragmentManager() method

3.Organize or update the imports

Source-

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: Thank you Kanwaljit Singh and Apoorv. it is working now. Thanks once again for your valuable time sharing for me